# C# Deserializing to a dictionary<string, Object>

Tags: c#, vb.net, dictionary, deserialization

I'm writing a C#/VB application to connect to a database and do stuff with the data.
I was given this code to take a serialized byte array and deserialized it, which is then written to a Dictionary
The line of code is:

```
Dictionary<string, Object> DictionaryEmployee = (Dictionary<string, Object> Deserializer(byteArrayEmp));
```

The errors I'm getting are exceedingly unhelpful.
"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" if I mouse over Object
and "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' requires 2 type arguments if I mouse over Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean:

```
Dictionary<string, Object> DictionaryEmployee = (Dictionary<string, Object>) Deserializer(byteArrayEmp);
```

It's just a misplacement of the cast closing parenthesis.

Comment: Of course that's it. Thank you, I could have sworn I tried casting.